# Only fetch structure entries that are first level or sub level that don't have a parent

Tags: structure, pagination

I have a Structure with my entries in. How can I hide the parent entries that contain children? I still want to show the parents children.

For example I want all the below entries bar "About" and "Services"

```
- Home
- About
    - Sub
    - Sub
    - Sub
- Stuff
- Services
    - Sub
    - Sub
    - Sub
- Things
```

So, this is my code right now

```
{# Set parameters for prev/next elements list #}
{% set params = craft.entries.section('pages') %}

{# Get the prev/next elements #}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(params) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(params) %}
```

Do I need to modify the params to remove the entries that are parents?

Comment: Is this only being used to navigate between the previous and next entry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`hasDescendants()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#hasDescendants) method to filter out any parent entry with children. You have to use an ElementCriteriaModel with `.getPrev()` and `.getNext()`.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section( 'pages' ) %}
{% set entryIds = [] %}

{% for entry in entries %}
  {% if not entry.hasDescendants() %}
    {% set entryIds = entryIds|merge( [entry.id] ) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% set criteria = craft.entries.id( entryIds ) %}

{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev( criteria ) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext( criteria ) %}
```

You will also need to add logic to get the first and last entry is next or previous is null.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to make no difference at all. It still gives me the next entry as being a parent entry.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, nope, now the prev next links don't show at all. No error though!

Comment: Ah no, you had changed the section name to test and i didn't pick that up! Works a treat, thank you!!!!